# Datatable set multiple title on excel sheet after excel export button click

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am using Datatable and correctly fetching data as expected but in a situation where I want to export data on excel button I want some data in A1 and B1 cell then my regular table content should export. I tried `customize` option of datatable but it didn't work like I needed.

Here is my code:

```
$("#boms-table").DataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": true,
    "info": false,
    "buttons": [{
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible:not(.exclude)'
            },
            title: "",
            customize: function(xlsx) {
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '50');
                var a1 = $('row c[r^="A1"]', sheet);
                a1.html('<is><t>' + materialPartcode + '</t></is>');
                var b1 = $('row c[r^="B1"]', sheet);
                b1.html('<is><t>' + materialDesc + " - BOM" + '</t></is>');
                $('row').eq(1).addClass('ignore');
                $('row c', sheet).each(function() {
                    if ($(this).index() > 1) {
                        var selectedRow = $(this).parent();
                        var columnIndex = $(this).index();
                        selectedRow.find('c[r^="A"]').eq(columnIndex).addClass('ignore');
                        selectedRow.find('c[r^="B"]').eq(columnIndex).addClass('ignore');
                    }
                });
                $('.ignore', sheet).attr('s', '2');
            },
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible:not(.exclude)'
            },
            title: materialPartcode + " - " + materialDesc + " - BOM",
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible:not(.exclude)'
            },
            title: materialPartcode + " - " + materialDesc + " - BOM",
        },
        'colvis'
    ],
}).buttons().container().appendTo('#boms-table_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
```

All I want is "materialPartcode" in A1 cell then "materialDesc" in B1 cell then all the table contents.